# Font awesome icons showing up as squares on IIS server 10 published ASP.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem where font awesome icons are showing up as squares (404 not found) on my published IIS server, but work in Visual studio debugger. I understand there are several answers to the same question, but they have been unsuccessful at fixing this issue. 
I am using the sb-admin template from startboostrap.com. Here's what i've done so far:

- Added Mime types to IIS manager: .woff and .woff2 as
  application/font-woff and application/font-woff2.
- Used this code in Index.html (Ignore the fact that there is references to several locations, I tried what was in the template as well as importing font-awesome myself, commented them each individually to see if SOMETHING would happen):

```
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">

    <!-- Page level plugin CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="Content/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/5.9.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <link href="fa_5.9/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fa_5.9/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fa_5.9/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

- Configured mime types in Web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
          <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
...
```

- Added to sb-admin.css (just to try it):

```
    @import url("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/5.9.0/css/font-awesome.css");
```

I've just about given up. I'm the sole developer for a company and this is my first shot at web development for them, and I don't actually think there is anything more I can try at this point. Does anyone have any clues on what may fix it?

---

EDIT: Fixed! I found that this stuff was actually unrelated to my problem. Whenever I "published" the project using visual studio, it would not include all the folders that links in the HTML code depended on (such as "vendor/"). I simply moved these folders into the folder that contained the published code and now the project works.

Comment: Have you even check the link? http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/font-awesome.css returns 404.

Comment: My apologies, I used an older link that worked but changed the version to keep things up to date, but thought that that one didn't have a 404 error. Older versions that worked did not have any effect on the program.

Comment: Figured it out, see edits in file!